# Why WPF window can not capture the Alt+F4 key on Windows 10?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I try to capture the Alt+F4 keys by adding KeyDown event handler on a WPF window, but it does not work.

However it works on a WinForms form. Why? How can I capture it on a WPF Window?

Comment: What is your purpose by capturing Alt+F4 keys? Do you want to prevent the window from closing with Alt+F4?

Answer (score 0):

Closing the window with "ALT+F4" seems to be hooked so, that even `Window.PrevieweyDown` being not called.

The possibilities here are to check the "Window.Closing":

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Alt) && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.F4))
    {
       //e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

or you can wire up a command depending on your needs (example where command is in window, that is window has property `ICommand SomeCommand`)

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="F4" Modifiers="Alt" Command="{Binding SomeCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"></KeyBinding>
</Window.InputBindings>
```